# How to pass the class fields in a method using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
class A {
    private TypeA a;
    Private TypeB b;
    ...
    Private TypeZ z;

    ...getters/setters...

   public add(Object o) {
       //blablabla
   }

   public testMethod() {
       add(a);
       add(b);
       add(c);
       ......
       add(z);

       /** here instead of calling add(a), add(b), add(c) one by one, I want to use reflection.
       **  something like:
       **  foreach(Field f : getDeclaredFields()) {
       **    add(f.getTheObjectReference());    <-- I made this method "getTheObjectReference" up
       **  }
       **/
   }
}
```

so in this example, I can use getDeclaredFields get all the fields Field[a-z], but once I have the Field object, how do I convert that to the actual object reference? there is no method from Field class called "getTheObjectReference". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use

```
for(Field field : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    Object o = field.get(this);
    add(o);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to get the field values for the "current" instance (the instance your `testMethod()` method was called on), you just want to call [`Field.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) with `this` as the target:

```
add(f.get(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible because the Field instance refers to a generic class method, not a specific class instance method!